# poor mans anova

Tags: anova, mixed-model, manova

**Background:**
I did something that I don't feel bad about, but I don't feel exactly right about.  I would like to get enough pointing in the right direction to teach myself and feel solidly good about it.

I discovered that both day of week and hour of day were driving variables in my training set when they shouldn't.  I made what is statistically and technically an excellent fit with neural networks.  I ran the NN on the full data to get a first prediction, then I adjusted the input data to have a single day of week, and single hour of day, to simulate as if it was all run at the same moment, and reran the NN.  The difference between the NN outputs I called "time error".  I took the mean value of that error for each hour in each day of week, and made a table of mean error.  I then traversed both the training and test data and for the apropriate time and day of week I subtracted the mean error.

I then handled the modified training and modified test data using a separate process.

My goal was to estimate the size of day of week and hour of day, and get a sense of how well the data behaved without them.  My next step is to properly remove the impact of day and hour from the data, an not do it as a "hack".

**Questions:**
Can you tell me what the "textbook" method is that I should have used instead of my previous approach?  What should I have done?

For my "next step" can you tell me the method that I should use?  What is it called?

I'm enough out of my element that I don't know what tag to use.  Is this anova? manova? nonlinear manova?  mixed effects? data scrubbing?

Comment: What is the goal of your analysis? What kind of data are you looking at?

Comment: If your are reasonably sure that day of week and hour don't affect your data but you find their effect and subtract it from the data, you are actually overfitting your model.

Comment: I am absolutely sure that day of week and hour DO affect my data.

Comment: @RobertF - My long-term goal is to get a decent predictor that is day of week and hour of day agnostic.  I need to remove that from my data because it is a relatively strong driver and it shouldn't be.  I know weekends drive part of the day of week, but I suspect the person executing the test is part of the day of week, and possibly the hour.

Comment: It sounds like a time series approach would be better - what exactly are you predicting? Is it a financial analysis? Traffic patterns?

Comment: @RobertF - I can't be specific there, sorry.  It is a scalar measurable that is a function of time, but the previous state does not fully predict the next state, so I guess it fails the Markov assumption.  It has some levels of seasonality, but it has other non-seasonal contributing factors.  I could do some multivariate analog of time series, possibly.  We could model it as sales at a restaurant if you like.

Comment: Hmm If the value you're predicting is independent of values at prior times but *is* dependent on day of week and time of day (like restaurant sales as you suggested), you could instead go with a standard regression model (not time series) and add dummy variables for each day of the week and hour of day when the sales took place.

Comment: Can you confirm that the standard regression model has a constant value for each level as its "basis function"?  So a dummy variable for nominal "monday" is going to be a single additive constant.  If there was an interaction of day of week by hour of day then monday by 11am would still be a nominal and would only have an additive constant.  Is that right?  This "feels" like a CART model.  Is there a clear difference between a CART with continuous and discrete inputs and a textbook dummy (additive constant) variable?

Comment: For What it's worth this [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.04342.pdf) plus a [diagrammatic Jacobian by Wan](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.38.4726&rep=rep1&type=pdf) plus Delta rule for the propagation of error feel like an answer and a road forward.